# Does Implicit Conversion in a Join Take up Spool Space in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, implicit-conversion

Does implicit conversion in a join in Teradata SQL have any impact on spool space, or is it only going to impact speed, or nothing?

Is there any performance difference between these two options below?

**Option 1**

```
SELECT A.test, B.test
FROM A
    INNER JOIN B
    ON A.NUM_COL = B.CHAR_COL
```

**Option 2**

```
SELECT A.test, B.test
FROM A
    INNER JOIN B
    ON A.NUM_COL = CAST(B.CHAR_COL AS INTEGER)
```

It seems there isn't much impact from my own experimentation, but wanted to confirm. I've Googled around and can't find much. Thanks.

Comment: Seems like your tables haven't been properly designed.

Comment: No difference, implicit or explicit cast executes the same.

Comment: Ok thank you. Yes you are right, they aren't designed properly lol, but unfortunately I can't change it right now.

Comment: There are two things to consider, #1: if you join on PI-columns it's no longer efficient, because it's no local join anymore (and then you actually need more spool) #2: the optimizer looses existing statistics due to the CAST which might lead to different (worse) plan.

Comment: Thanks dnoeth. Why would joining on PI columns not be efficient? Either way, this isn't a primary index in either table.

Good to know that CAST can remove statistics. Seems best to just use implicit conversion then.

Comment: Joins using the PI is only efficient when both columns share the same datatype (or a similar like INT & BIGINT, CHAR(20) and VARCHR(30)) because they hash the smae and can be joined without preparing a spool. But if the column is CASTed (implicitly or explicizly) it will hash differently, thus it must be spooled and distributed to match the other column's hash. I woul dprefer writing an explicit cast, because it will help fellow your coworkers to understand what's gong on. And you have control which column is converted, e.g. might be better to change a small instead of a huge table.

Comment: If you want to see what Teradata is doing behind the scenes for both statements, add the word "explain" in front of the query and look at the query plan.  I think that you will see data spooled for both of them.